# How to calculate continous variance of given set of functions?

Tags: probability, statistics

imagine we have a set of continuous functions over time, which are defined for certain time spans:

$$ Q_1(t) = 10 \times t \quad for \quad0<t<5$$ 
$$ Q_2(t) = 4 \times t \quad for \quad1<t<8$$ 
$$ Q_3(t) = 7 \times t \quad for \quad2<t<9$$ 
$$ ...$$ 
$$ Q_i(t) = r_i \times t \quad for \quad endpoint_{1.i} <t<endpoint_{2.i}$$

In total there maybe 1000s of equations like this. But it is easily possible to get any $Q(t)$.

I would like to calculate the variance of it. To calculate the discrete variance one could discretize the function in defined time steps.

But how is it possible to calculate the **continous variance** with this set of functions?

Comment: Sorry, but these are deterministic functions, so the variance is zero. Variance is a term from probability theory. If you mean something else, you have to say what you mean :-).

Comment: Okay good point. I am looking for a measure to describe the 'level of fluctuation' over a certain time span. Where if Q=const. the 'level of fluctuation' is zero e.g.

Comment: Sorry but this does not help to understand what you mean. We have still deterministic functions and don't know how you define your *level of fluctuation*. If you can't define it more precisely, you will have to wait until somebody with a larger crystal ball than mine is passing by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In statistics, the variability (variance) is defined for continuous random variable $X$ as:

$$Var(X):=\int_{\omega \in \Omega} (X(\omega)-E[X(\omega)])^2 dP(\omega)$$

Normally, $\Omega$ is the set of possible outcomes of an experiment (e.g., a particular string of heads and tails out of N tosses), and $X(\omega)$ is the value of the random variable for a specific outcome $\omega$ (e.g., number of heads in a particular string of tosses).

As pointed out by Karl, your functions are deterministic. This implies that $\Omega_i:=\{t\in[a_i,b_i]\}$ and $X(\omega)=Q_i(\omega)$. But nevertheless, it is a valid sample space (albeit degenerate).

Now, the outcomes in $\Omega$ are not random, so we cannot apply probability theory and its interpretation to these functions. However, we can apply some simple measure theory by replacing the probability measure $P(\omega)$ with a measure defined over intervals $\omega\subset [a_i,b_i]$

$$\mu(\omega)=\frac{l(\omega)}{b_i-a_i}$$, where $l(\omega)$ is the total length of the interval $\omega$.

This is possible because probability measures are just a *type* of measure, so our formula for the variance can be generalized to non-probability measures. We now get something I will call the "mean square variation"(MSV):

$$MSV(Q_i):=\int\limits_{a_i}^{b_i} (Q_i(t)-M[Q_i(t)])^2 d\mu(t)$$

Where $M[Q_i]:=\int\limits_{a_i}^{b_i} Q_i(t) d\mu(t)$

Finally, to complete this, we recognize that $d\mu(t)=\frac{dt}{b_i-a_i}$ and we get:

$$MSV(Q_i):=\frac{1}{b_i-a_i}\int\limits_{a_i}^{b_i} (Q_i(t)-M[Q_i(t)])^2 dt$$

where: $M[Q_i]:=\frac{1}{b_i-a_i}\int\limits_{a_i}^{b_i} Q_i(t) dt$ is just the average value of the function over its domain.

Thus, MSV is a measure of the degree to which your function fluctuates about its mean value. Probabilistically, we could interpret it to mean that if you chose a values of $t$ in the domain of $Q_i$, according to a uniform density over the allowable t-values, then the variance of $Q_i$ would equal the $MSV$

Comment: Thank you, I guess this it. Also thanks for explaining it in this great detail.